# Google Cloud Function REST API Authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, restful-authentication

I would like to utilize the following API from Google: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/

I make a [GET /v1/{name}/locations](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations/list) request to the endpoint and receive an HTTP 401 Error. This means I have not set up authentication.
For reference, here is the code I am running:

```
import requests

def list(project_id):
    endpoint = 'https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/'
    endpoint += project_id
    endpoint += '/locations'
    r = requests.get(endpoint)
    return r
```

The documentation linked states that I am required to have one of the two following OAuth scopes:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudfunctions

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

How do I acquire these scopes? I have already downloaded a credentials file and exported an environment variable as listed in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/docs/common/auth). I am currently not using these credentials anywhere, since it seems like a security risk to send a private key over plain text.

Could someone please explain how to turn this 401 Authentication Error into a 200 Success (or any other error)?

Comment: Is there are reason that you do not want to use a Google SDK? You are calling an endpoint using HTTP Get with no authorization. I wrote an article that explains how to make Google API calls with service account credentials https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/